# Is it guaranteed that the kill() function will not return until the signal handler has done if a process kills itself?

Tags: linux, signals

Imagine the following program written in C:

```
void handler(int signo) {
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "handler\n", 8);
}
int main() {
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler);
    kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "after kill\n", 11);
}
```

If I run this program in Linux, is it possible the output is as follow:

```
after kill
handler
```

I tried many times, and the above result didn't appear.

Comment: You should explain much more why do you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`puts` is not good inside signals handlers. Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), `puts` is *not* async-signal-safe.  You should use [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) inside a signal handler (not `puts`).

<sup>You have edited your question to use `write` instead of  `puts`</sup>

And if you insist in wrongly using `puts` you should at least call `fflush`. But both are wrong inside signal handlers.

(Don't forget that `stdout`is buffered)

BTW, it might happen (notably in multi-threaded application, where the signal handler is not running in the same thread that `kill(2)`-s the signal) that the signal handler is invoked after returning of `kill`

I'm not sure that you are guaranteed that the signal handler of a single-threaded process is returning before `kill`, even if I believe that would happen on most Linux kernels. What you should be sure is that the signal handler would *eventually* be called (but you cannot be sure on *when* exactly). Also, a kernel is permitted to lose some signals (e.g. if an external thing or process is sending a lot of same signals). So called [POSIX real-time](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/realtime.html) signals are the exception, not the norm (see also [this](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/all-about-linux-signals?page=9))

If you have an [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (e.g. around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)) and accept to have Linux-specific code
you could consider using [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) and polling it inside your event loop.

Comment: ok,ok. You're right. And I've turned it into write(). But what I actually want to ask is that whether the kill() function can return before the signal handler has been called.

Comment: I don't understand why you ask. What matters to you is *observable behavior*, and in some cases (e.g multi-threaded applications) the signal handler would be called *after* the `kill`

Comment: I'm only concerned about the behaviour of THIS application. There is only a single thread, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If the SIGINT signal is delivered to the process after the `puts("looping");` statement, then it will print the string "handler1" in the `handle1` function. When the `kill` function returns, the output depends on when the SIGUSR1 signal will be delivered to the process. I think you can use the `sigsuspend` function to make sure it's what you want. By the way, before `kill` function returns, at least an unblocked signal is delivered to the process.

The following code outputs what you want and you need to block the SIGUSR1 signal first.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handler(int signo) {
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "handler\n", 8);
}
int main() {

    sigset_t newmask, oldmask;
    sigemptyset( &newmask );
    sigaddset( &newmask, SIGUSR1 );

    signal(SIGUSR1, handler);

    // block the SIGUSR1 signal
    sigprocmask ( SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask );

    kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "after kill\n", 11);

    // reset the signal mask
    sigprocmask ( SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I made my question complicated. I edited it, and now it is reflecting what I really want to ask.